# Any tool to add linenumbers in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

All,

Is there any tool to add line numbers in jquery to a textarea.

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google `jquery line numbers textarea` revealed: http://alan.blog-city.com/jquerylinedtextarea.htm